# How to make 2 section planes with section extension, disable edges lines and enable arrow?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I recently discovered an method from `Autodesk.Section` tool called `setPlane` using this, I can set one or more cutplanes into model (using setSectionPlane the previous cutplane disappear) and achieved this result:

[image: double cutplane]

But with a few problems:

- The second cutplane diaplys model's bounds
- Arrow's active but I can't move it
- Can't select the previous plane to move it

So, my goal is to be able to set two cutplanes, display no edges lines and be able to dinamic select one and move it.

Comment: Hi Gustavo,
Was the answer helpful in understanding the section tool functionality in your context?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sectionext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Section')
console.log(sectionext.mode)   // 'x' or 'y' or 'z' or 'box'
```

At any given point, the section tool can only be in one mode, not multiple.
So, you have to deactivate and activate again. This may not be as smooth as you're expecting, but this is the only way.

Comment: Hi Varun, thanks for the answer, so, "section tool can only be in one mode, not multiple" means that my goal is not possible, assuming that I deactive and active it again, the first cutplane will be lost, right?

Comment: yes, that's correct.